# Open a Standard Jet DB 4.0 file (*.vmd)

Tags: database, windows, standards, jet

I downloaded a database file with the extension "VMD".
Now I'm looking for a windows software which can open this file, so that i can see all the included tables to (later) export some of them info csv.

When I open the downloaded file with a normal text editor, the header of the file tells me

> Standard Jet DB 4.0

When when I try to open it with usual db software (like Microsoft Access) there is an error like

> unrecognizable database format

I'm a little bit confused. The file has a "Standard Jet DB 4.0" header but can't be opened with usual software.

Is the some great software which could open this file it?

Answer (score 6):

Rename the file to .mdb suffix and then try opening in Access again. You may need to use a password, in which case try [Access PassView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/accesspv.html) as suggested in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/180400/157229).

Comment: Wow.. It worked !!! Really unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

A quick addition to this thread,

For future reference, in the latest MSAccess for this post, you need to change filetype to 'All Files (*)' to be able to select your MSAccess db file. Then you can select any file, and then it should open as normal, disregarding the extension;

[image]